# Ruby. Symbol '=' in to the setter name and initialization of an object

Tags: ruby, object, setter, initializer

```
class Item

    def name=(name_value)   
        @name = name_value
    end

    def name
        @name
    end

end
```

In the first case:

```
item = Item.new
item.name=("value")
puts item.class
```

I keep getting.

```
Item
```

In the second case:

```
item = Item.new.name=("value")
puts item.class
```

I have

```
String
```

Why? I do not understand the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby sees your second example as this

```
item = Item.new.name = 'value'
```

Return value of an assignment operator is the value being assigned. `Item.new.name = 'value'` returns `'value'` and so does `item = 'value'`.

```
class Item
  def name=(name_value)
    @name = "processed #{name_value}"
  end

  def name
    @name
  end
end

item = Item.new
item2 = item.name = "value" # your example code

item2 # => "value"
item.name # => "processed value"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, assignment expressions evaluate to the value that is being assigned.

I.e.:

```
foo = 'bar'
```

evaluates to `'bar'`

So, in your case

```
Item.new.name=("value")
```

which would more idiomatically be written like this:

```
Item.new.name = 'value'
```

the value being assigned is the string `'value'`.

So, `Item.new.name = 'value'` evaluates to `'value'` (with the side-effect of calling the `name=` method, of course), which means that

```
item = Item.new.name = 'value'
```

evaluates to

```
item = 'value'
```

And in the end, `item` has the value `'value'`, which is a `String`.

Comment: Our answers are like twins :)

Answer (score 0):

on the second case you are creating a new Item and setting the name, when you set the name it returns a string, which you assign to item variable.
you should use the first form

or when inherits from ActiveRecord:

```
item = Item.new(:name=>"value")
```